# What is the best way to delete node with connected nodes using spring data neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

There is a tree structure stored in neo4j database. Need to delete a node with all the child nodes. I can propose two approaches so far:

1. Write a custom query to delete the node and all its children along
   with their relationships at DB level.
2. Delete a node itself and run a recursive function at the separate thread for deleting all the children along with their relationship at the application level.

Can one estimate the effectiveness of these approaches and determine which one is better (faster) without the benchmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach #2, which uses threads to concurrently delete nodes/relationships in the same subgraph, is prone to errors, and should be avoided.

When deleting a relationship, neo4j's default locking mechanism will lock the relationship AND its endpoints; this can cause deadlock errors when multiple threads concurrently attempt to delete nodes/relationships in the same subgraph.

Also, a thread may discover that a node/relationship it is attempting to work on has disappeared (due to the actions of other threads).

Here is a sample Cypher query that uses approach #1. It should find all distinct nodes in a `Foo/BAR` tree and delete the tree (using `DETACH DELETE`, which @ToreEschliman also suggested):

[EDITED]

```
MATCH p=(a:Foo {id: 123})-[:BAR*0..]->(b:Foo)
WITH COLLECT(b) AS ns1
UNWIND ns1 AS n
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT n) AS ns2
FOREACH(y IN ns2 | DETACH DELETE y);
```

[UPDATE]

Based on new info from the comments, here is how to delete the entire tree rooted at a specific `CodeSet` node:

```
MATCH p=(root:CodeSet {id: 123})<-[*0..]-(node)
DETACH DELETE p;
```

*The `MATCH` pattern used assumes that all the descendant nodes are connected via relationships directed towards the root node.*

Comment: I may be missing something. Is there some reason you can't COLLECT b and use your FOREACH DETACH DELETE on that collection instead of gathering all nodes in every single matched path? Seems like with your approach there are going to be a ton of duplicates, and even if your DISTINCT deals with that, I'm wondering what this buys you.

Comment: @InverseFalcon: Thanks. I have edited my answer to use `COLLECT(b)` instead of `REDUCE(s = [], x IN NODES(p) | s + x)`, which should indeed be faster. However, `ns1` can still contain duplicates, so the rest of the query is the same.

Comment: @cybersam I tried out both the updated query and the original one. The orignal query works for me, while the updated one just deletes the relationship (leaving nodes detached). Many thanks for your time.

Comment: @cybersam Is it possible to make this also work for the node *without children?* Right now this leaves such nodes undeleted.

Comment: Are you using `*0..` in the relationship pattern? The `0` should cause childless nodes to be deleted.

Comment: @cybersam yes, but I added checking the node to be deleted by id like this:
`MATCH p=(a:Node)-[:SUBTREE_OF*0..]->(b:CodeSet)  WHERE ID(b)={id} WITH REDUCE(s = [], x IN NODES(p) | s + x) AS ns1 UNWIND ns1 AS n WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT n) AS ns2 FOREACH(y IN ns2 | DETACH DELETE y);`

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, what  you are trying to do seems strange. You want to: (A) delete all paths that start with a `Node` node and end with a `CodeSet` node with the specified ID, AND (B) delete all `Node` nodes without any children? That would potentially leave standing other subgraphs rooted at `Node`. Also, any subgraphs that may be descendants of the node with the specified ID will be left intact (and possibly disconnected from anything else). Is this what you want?

Comment: @cybersam I have a tree structure that starts with a `CodeSet` root node and `Node`s are its children; I want `CodeSet` or `Node` to be deleted with all its children (just like a regular branch removal operation in the tree structure). So in fact, I want exact the opposite: to avoid unbound entries. The problem is: query works when `CodeSet` has `Node` children and not when it doesn't. I hope this makes sense to you. I can provide a test data sample/create another question if it makes this easier. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate, yes, and you should estimate that the first one is always faster. If you can write a query that identifies all your bad nodes, just do so, then `DETACH DELETE` those nodes at the end. One transaction, one Cypher translation, and then the rest is handled in specialized, purpose-built database code. If you can come up with a faster way to do it at application level, you should be writing a competing database.